# Finding roots of a characteristic equation of higher order ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Original DE:  $y^{(8)} + 8y^{(4)} + 16 = 0$
The $^{(x)}$ means the order of the derivative.
Characteristics equation is:
$r^8+8r^4+16=0$
$[r^4 + 4]^2=0$

I don't know how to find the complex roots of $r^4+4$. Is it method similar to finding the complex root of a 2nd order DE?

My attempt:
$r^4 =-4$
$r=\pm 2i$

Answer (score 1):

We have

$$r^4=-4=4e^{i\pi}\iff r=\sqrt2 \exp\left(i\frac\pi4+ik\frac\pi2\right),\; k=0,1,2,3$$

Comment: How'd you come up with that? How could we convert that into separate linearly independent solutions?